# Laplace transform of convolution of dirac delta distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, laplace-transform

So I have a stochastic process which counts a number of clicks in a certain given interval of time $[0,t]$. The number of clicks recorded is given by,

$$ N(t)  = \big[\int_{0}^{t} \sum_i \delta(\tau-t_i)\mathrm{d}\tau \big ] $$

And the general $l$-th moment is given by, where $\langle... \rangle$ is a stochastic average.

$$\langle N^l(t) \rangle = \big \langle \big[\int_{0}^{t} \sum_i \delta(\tau-t_i)\mathrm{d}\tau \big ]^l \big \rangle $$

In general, I have been able to show, $$C_m(t) = \langle N(t)[N(t)-1]...[N(t)-m+1] \rangle  = \left( \int_0^{t} \prod_{i=1}^{m} \mathrm{d}t_i \rho_m(t_1,t_2..t_m) \right) $$ These are factorial moments for this point process and $\rho_m$ defines the $m$-particle density. One then finds,

$$\rho_2 = \sum_{i\neq j} \langle \delta (\tau_1 - t_i) \delta (\tau_2 - t_j)\rangle $$

Now, the process is stationary, Markovian, such that  $$\rho_1(t) = k$$
$$\rho_2(t_1,t_2) = \rho_2(|t_1-t_2|)$$
I need to show that $$\hat{\rho}_2 (s) = k \frac{\hat{f}(s)}{1-\hat{f}(s)}$$

Symbols with a caret indicate a Laplace transform, and $$f = \langle \delta(t_i-t_{i+1}-\tau)\rangle$$

I have also shown,

$$\hat{f}(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st} f(t) \mathrm{d}t = \sum \frac{(-1)^l s^l \langle \tau^l \rangle }{l!}$$ where $\langle \tau^l \rangle = \langle (t_i - t_{i+1})^l\rangle $

Using these results, and the fact that $\rho_1$ is a constant and $\rho_2$ depends only in the difference in time, I need to derive the relation for the Laplace transform of $\rho_2$ The form of the formula is suggestive, that I am summing a geometric series, and it seems to me like I am supposed to go from a convolution to a a sum of product of Laplace transforms (since the Laplace transform of a convolution is a product of Laplace transforms).

$rho_1$ entering the expression for $\rho_2$ is suggestive of reducing $\rho_2$ to a conditional probability.

I have derived that  And i have been taking the laplace transform of this expression but can't seem to massage it into the right form.

Comment: I don't understand your notations. You want the two variables Laplace transform of  $h(t_1,t_2)= g(t_1-t_2)$ ? Then $h(t) = f(Mt)$ where $f(t_1,t_2) =1_{t_1 > 0} g(t_2)$ and $Mt = (t_1,t_1-t_2)$ so $H(s) = \frac{1}{|\det(M)|} F(M^{-\top} s)$ where $F(s) = \frac{1}{s_1} G(s_2)$

Comment: In this special case, though my function only depends on the difference between $t_1$ and $t_2$

Comment: Hi @reuns thanks for the input! I tried using your hint, but I still can't get it into the desired form..

Comment: $\rho_2(t_1,t_2) = \rho_2(t_1 - t_2)$ doesn't makes sense. $\rho_2$ has two variables in the LHS and one in the RHS!

Comment: What I mean is $\rho (|t_2-t_1|)$ It only depends on the relative time.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla. It's an abuse of notation common among physicists (and some mathematicians). It means that $\rho_2(t_1, t_2)$ only depends on $t_1-t_2$. Therefore we might treat $\rho$ as a function of two variables or a function of one variable composed with $(t_1, t_2) \mapsto t_1-t_2 : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. This reduces bloat caused by having several function names, but have the negative effect that it might be confusing (to pure mathematicians).

Comment: @md2perpe Thank you! Guilty as charged for abuse of notation.

Comment: The biggest obstacle for helping you is that it's not clear how things are defined. You say $\rho_1(t) = k,$ and $\rho_2(t_1-t_2) = \rho_2(|t_1-t_2|),$ and $\hat{\rho}_2(s) = k \hat{f}(s) / (1 - \hat{f}(s)),$ so obviously $\rho_1$ comes into $\rho_2$ in some way, but how and why? And what is $f$? How did that get into the transform? We miss a lot of context, I think. Especially: How is $\rho_2$ defined?

Comment: @md2perpe I have added more context. $\rho_2$ is defined through the m-factorial moments, as described. thanks!

Comment: If you have a distribution of two variables $h(\tau_1,\tau_2) = \sum_{i\neq j} \delta (\tau_1 - t_i) \delta (\tau_2 - t_j)$ with the $t_i > A$ then $H(s_1,s_2)=\int_{A- \epsilon}^\infty \int_{A-\epsilon}^\infty h(\tau_1,\tau_2) e^{-s_1 \tau_1}e^{-s_2 \tau_2}d\tau_1 d \tau_2 = \sum_{i\neq j} e^{-s_1 t_i} e^{-s_2 t_j}$. Your $\langle. \rangle$ is linear so $\int_{A- \epsilon}^\infty \int_{A-\epsilon}^\infty \langle  h(\tau_1,\tau_2)\rangle  e^{-s_1 \tau_1}e^{-s_2 \tau_2}d\tau_1 d \tau_2 = \langle H(s_1,s_2) \rangle$. If your $t_i$ are random then it reduces to its moments generating functions